# vtkArrayCalculator - Segmentation fault when accessing the output

Tags: c++, vtk, paraview

I want to use vtkArrayCalculator, for use in a Paraview filter, as described here: [ArrayCalculatorExample](https://itk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/ArrayCalculator)

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkArrayCalculator> calculator = vtkSmartPointer<vtkArrayCalculator>::New();
calculator->SetInputData(input);
calculator->AddScalarArrayName("u");
calculator->SetFunction("u+1");
calculator->SetResultArrayName("wind_velocity");
calculator->Update();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray> windVelocity = 
        vtkFloatArray::SafeDownCast(calculator->GetStructuredGridOutput()->GetPointData()->GetArray("wind_velocity"));
```

Now when I want to access the data with (or similar commands)

```
    windVelocity->GetValue(0);
```

I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

"input" is a vtkStructuredGrid and "u" is a vtkDataArray (that can be downcast to a vtkFloatArray without problem). "u" can be accessed by

```
input->GetPointData()->GetArray("u");
```

Every hint to what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I already tried the following

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray> windVelocity = vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
windVelocity->DeepCopy(vtkFloatArray::SafeDownCast(calculator->GetStructuredGridOutput()->GetPointData()->GetArray("wind_velocity")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to split up the long chain of `vtkFloatArray::SafeDownCast(calculator->GetStructuredGridOutput()->GetPointData()->GetArray("wind_velocity"))` and use a debugger to see what the intermediate results are.

When reading the definition of `GetArray`, it states that under various conditions the function might return `NULL`. Check the return value of `GetArray`; it is very likely that you do not get back what you expect.

> vtkDataArray* vtkFieldData::GetArray  (   const char *    arrayName   )
>   inline
>
> Not recommended for use. Use GetAbstractArray(const char *arrayName) instead.
>
> Return the array with the name given. Returns NULL if array not found.
>   A NULL is also returned if the array with the given name is not a
>   vtkDataArray. To access vtkStringArray, vtkUnicodeStringArray, or
>   vtkVariantArray, use GetAbstractArray(const char *arrayName).

Comment: Thanks to your tip I looked again at this command and the error occurs when I use the vtkFloatArray::SafeDownCast() command, otherwise it does not return NULL. I found out, it actually returns a vtkDoubleArray. I thought, VTK is able to downcast from a double to a float array, but apparently this does not work in my case. Thank you for looking into my problem, it helped a lot!